How can I get the Windows Access Manager to demand a userID/PW from AcquireTokenInteractive.WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin) when it does not demand PW
I am using MSAL in a WPF desktop client to authenticate against an Azure EntraID. I am using WAM and redirect to the client app. I have chosen not to use AcquireTokenSilent. When I try to authenticate, I am presented with a list of accounts that are on my computer. I am using the AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin) option. However, I am able to get an active token after selecting an account though I am not presented with a request for the password. I have disabled the token cache. I have cleaned out the browser's cookies. I have used App.PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync to remove the accounts from the WAM.There are no SSOs that I am aware of on the computer.
Where is the OS getting the PW from to get a token? Especially when I have specified ForceLogin?

It's possible that the OS is retrieving the password from cached credentials or Windows Credential Manager. Ensure to clear any cached credentials related to the Azure AD account from Windows Credential Manager. Additionally, double-check for any other applications or services utilizing single sign-on (SSO) mechanisms that could be affecting the authentication flow.
